# Remove header border

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble removing a 20px or so space above the header navigation bar on a website:
**redacted**

I can remove it by removing the "position: absolute;" attribute, but then the homepage doesn't load it's navigation bar right - so I'm lost on how to fix this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
.no-shadow {
    box-shadow: none;
    margin-top: 50px; <-- This line
    padding-top: 90px;
```

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

do you mean the `box-shadow`? Thats causing your 'border' on the header element.

https://infinit.io/_/376BJD3

Comment: No, I mean that entire upper area. If I remove the box shadow then that entire upper area is white - but then the header itself is too large (if that makes sense). I just want to remove everything above the logo area so it's flush with the top of the page.